# Concurrent LogIn Access ASP.NET using Threads recommended?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, iis

I have a question, I hope you can help me, Thank you in advance.

I am working in a project, a WEB Application hosted in IIS; the approach is that I have a LogIn for users, but the LogIn must allow one user to login at time, so if two users are trying to access to the site at the same time only one should access, while the other one waits until the first is logged in. I thought of using threads, with a lock statement in the Sign In validation, but I don't know if it is a good practice to use threads in this scenario, due to multiple users may try to Log In at the same time, and only one must access at time. Also, I need to have a log for the users in the order they have accessed the site, to verify that two users did not access at the same time.

Is multithreading a good practice or recommendation for making this?
Any suggestions? Thank you so much.

Comment: Just asking, why should only one have access at a time?

Comment: It is a requirement, maybe it doesn't make sense but is a homework. The goal is to understand how multithreading does work.

Answer (score 0):

First off, when using threads its good practice to avoid anything that will block a thread, if at all possible.

You could use a lock which would cause incoming threads to block until the first thread has completed the login process, although I can't see how this would help in understanding multithreading. This will only help in learning how to block threads, which you should try to avoid at all costs, threads are expensive.

IMHO you should never have more threads than CPU cores, use the threadpool, understand the difference between compute bound and I\O bound threads. I say again threads are expensive, in both time and memory.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is solution is not so much about multithreading - but i would do something like this:

```
public class SingleUserLock : IDisposable
{
    private SingleUserSemaphore _parent;

    public SingleUserLock(SingleUserSemaphore parent)
    {
        _parent = parent;
    }

    public bool IsLoggedIn => _parent?.CurrentUser == this;

    public void Unlock()
    {
        _parent?.Unlock();
        _parent = null;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Unlock();
    }
}

public class SingleUserSemaphore
{
    private readonly object _lockObject = new object();
    public SingleUserLock CurrentUser { get; private set; }

    public bool TryLogin()
    {
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(_lockObject))
        {
            CurrentUser = new SingleUserLock(this);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Unlock()
    {
        try
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_lockObject);
            CurrentUser = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { };
    }
}
```

Register an instance of SingleUserSemaphore as a Singleton in your DependecyInjection framework for the Web application. Every time a user logs in, you get the singleton SingleUserSemaphore instance and call TryLogin. If true you can the store SingleUserLock in the Session if possible. 
For every request check the session for `IsLoggedIn == true`.
When the user logs out you call the returned `SingleUserLock.Unlock();` from the session or directly `SingleUserSemaphore.Unlock();`

Now the challenge will be, if the user never Logs out. Your web application will be locked forever. To avoid this you could make an Update method on `SingleUserSemaphore` with a timestamp for every request made by the logged in user. So when a user logs in, you also check for last activity...

Good luck with you homework.